# Even after converting the Audio from Mono to Stereo in ffmpeg the video still has No sound Unless

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I Change the audio Mode in VLC from Stereo to Mono then the Audio will play Normal

I used ffmpeg to convert the audio to Stereo using this

```
ffmpeg -i bokan_test_1.mkv -map 0 -map -0:s? -c:v copy -c:a ac3 -ac 2 -b:a 640k "E:\Test\output.S01E05.mkv"
```

I even used Handbrake still No audio in VLC unless I change the audio mode to Mono

Edit:
full log when running the ffmpeg command above

```
E:\test audio>ffmpeg -i bokan_test_1.mkv -map 0 -map -0:s? -c:v copy -c:a ac3 -ac 2 -b:a 640k "E:\Test\output.S01E06.mkv"
ffmpeg version 4.3.1-2021-01-01-essentials_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 10.2.0 (Rev5, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-sdl2 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-libgme --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-librubberband
  libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
  libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
  libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
  libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
  libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
  libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
  libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'bokan_test_1.mkv':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : libebml v1.3.0 + libmatroska v1.4.0
    creation_time   : 2015-07-27T22:38:36.000000Z
  Duration: 00:20:01.02, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3497 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(progressive), 1440x1080, SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 1k tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)
    Stream #0:1(ara): Audio: aac (HE-AAC), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> ac3 (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, matroska, to 'E:\Azmi\output.S01E06.mkv':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High) (H264 / 0x34363248), yuv420p(progressive), 1440x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], q=2-31, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc (default)
    Stream #0:1(ara): Audio: ac3 ([0] [0][0] / 0x2000), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 640 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.91.100 ac3
frame=35994 fps=5263 q=-1.0 Lsize=  595496kB time=00:20:01.03 bitrate=4061.8kbits/s speed= 176x
video:501161kB audio:93829kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.085007%
```

Comment: Show the complete log from your command.

Comment: i post above the full log above from the ffmpeg command just one think to add that even with the original video vlc the reporting it as stereo but when playing it the audio will not work unless i change the audio mode inside vlc to Mono

Comment: I'm unable to duplicate the issue with VLC 3.0.12 on Linux. Is VLC the only player giving you trouble? Does the [VLC log](https://superuser.com/a/1511107/) show anything?